# How to send a custom header with every request to localhost during development?

Tags: http, debugging, cors, http-headers, localhost

Is it possible to somehow send a custom header with every browser request to perhaps a specific domain? I have a CORS situation where I have allowed localhost to be visible (if origin is from localhost, allow it), but I would like to avoid that in theory without having to configure a `local.dev` sort of domain. Is there a way to just have the browser send a header with every request to my CORS domain? That would be nice, then I could just do basic auth with the header hack, and only allow localhost on CORS if it also has the special header. Anything like that possible?

I am imagining something to do with the chrome devtools / debugger, perhaps you can just specify some cookie or header or something through that, and have it be persistent for days and weeks.

Comment: You can inject headers into requests with a Chrome extension that uses https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/